# Enviar variable js a php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, dompdf

Quiero enviar 4 variables nom, email, data y hora que tengo declaradas en el principio del .js y las quiero enviar cuando hago el window.location al archivo .php de index.php, para posterior crear un archivo pdf.

Pero no se que codigo tengo de escribir en el js, en el archivo php ya tengo declaradas las varibles esperando. como estas $nom = $_POST["nom"];

```
$('#reserves').submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
  var nom = $.trim($("#nom").val());    
  var apellidos =$.trim($("#apellidos").val());   
  var email =$.trim($("#email").val()); 
  var telefon =$.trim($("#telefon").val()); 
  var persones =$.trim($("#persones").val()); 
  var data =$.trim($("#data").val()); 
  var hora =$.trim($("#hora").val()); 
  var personesContades =$.trim($("#result-persones").html());
  var numero_persones =$.trim($("#result-hora").html());

    $.ajax({
       url:"bd/reservar.php",
       type:"POST",
       datatype: "json",
       data: {nom:nom, apellidos:apellidos, email:email, telefon:telefon, persones:persones, data:data, hora:hora}, 
       success:function(data){               
           if(data == "null"){
               Swal.fire({
                   type:'error',
                   title:'Ups. Error al realitzar la reserva',
               });
           }else{
               Swal.fire({
                   type:'success',
                   title:'¡Reserva realitzada correctament!',
                   text: "¡Revisa el correu!",
                   confirmButtonColor:'#3085d6',
                   confirmButtonText:'Acceptar'
               }).then((result) => {
                   if(result.value){
                    window.location.href = "pdf/index.php";
                   }
               })
           }
       }    
    });
```

});

Comment: Ya la estarías mandando aquí: `data: {nom:nom, apellidos:apellidos, email:email, telefon:telefon, persones:persones, data:data, hora:hora},` ¿cuál es el problema? Aunque esa clave `data` (antes de hora) ¿? yo la llamaría de otra forma. Y, ¿por qué hablas de `window.location`? No tiene nada que ver con Ajax, debes pasar los datos al archivo que pones en el parámetro `url` de la petición Ajax, que se encargará de recibir / procesar / devolver los datos con un simple `echo`, no te líes con location ni historias, Ajax es más simple de lo que se cree.

Comment: Sí, ojo con el `var data =$.trim($("#data").val()); ` y el `data:data`, pues se va a liar con otras cosas... tómatelo como si fuera una palabra reservada y no la uses así. Cámbiala por `datareserva` o lo que se te ocurra.